# Ruby comparing hashes built from non-associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, hash

I am trying to compare hashes, they reference a complex set of associations. Payments are managed by an engine within the app so there is no `belongs_to:` / `has_many:` relationships between it and users(which is on the main application). However i can pull user from the main app using a service.

I have a Payments table - in engine

```
# Table name: payments
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  account_id              :integer
#  currency                :string(255)
....
```

The Account table just maps users to accounts - in engine

```
# Table name: account
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id                 :integer
....
```

The User table also has a column for currency, this is to mark what currency he opted to pay in during the sign-up phase.

```
# Table name: user
#
#  id                      :integer          not null, primary key
#  currency                :string(255)
....
```

We have an issue where sometimes users pay in different currencies, I would like to build a hash where `:payment_id => true/false`(where this would be user.currency == payment.currency), something where i can count the offences I was thinking of saving the payment_id just incase they wanted detailed error data.

What I ended up doing was.

1. Building a `payments Hash` with `account_id: currency`
2. Building a `accounts Hash` using only account_ids found in step 1 `id: user_id`
3. Rebuilding the payments hash by replacing account_id: with user_id:
4. Building a `users Hash` with `users_id: currency`
5. Iterating through each user_id and ticking a counter when payment_hash[user_id] != user_hash[user_id]

looks something like this

```
def inconsistancy_count(payments)
  #list of account ids involved with the payments made
  matching_account_ids = Recon::Account.where(account_id: payments).map(&:id)

  # list of users that are attached to those accounts above
  user_ids = Recon:Account.where(account_id: matching_account_ids).map(&:user_id)

  # Payment hash mapping account_id and currency
  payment_currency_hash = Recon::Payment.where(account_id: matching_account_ids).reduce({}) {|hash, payment| hash.merge(payment.account_id => payment.currency)}

  #build a hash using the user service.
  main_app_user_currency_hash = Recon.user_service.get_user_info_from_ids(user_ids)

  inconsistancy_count = 0
  matching_user_ids.each do |user|
    inconsistancy_count += 1 if main_app_user_currency_hash[user] != payment_currency_hash[user]
  end
  inconsistancy_count
end
```

The above won't work because the payments hash is still based off account_id and not user_id.

I feel my route is very round about it seems as if this method has a ton of things it should do. Is there a better way of accomplishing this

Comment: If the engine table is in the same database as the main app you should still be able to join to it. Just because the models are defined in an engine, doesn't mean you can't access them and their data.

Comment: Yeah the only problem with building it like that is when we eventually separate this engine to a micro-service it will be tightly coupled to the main application. I guess if the data is so tightly coupled I should talk to everyone about pulling this into the main application.